# How to resolve net::ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR on server-side?

Tags: google-chrome, server-side, quic

Some users have been reporting connection errors with Chrome after implementing reCaptcha. The issue appears to be intermittent and when we check the affected user's browser, we found "net::ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR"

Disabling quic protocol on Chrome resolves it but as developers, does anyone know how we can resolve this without requesting every visitor to disable Quic?

Comment: have same problem in 2020

Comment: Mm-hmm. 'Me too' (in 2021). I suppose that, while HTTP/3 is still a protocol being actively developed — it's not a RFC yet! — we're out of luck...